# Does It affects Kafka performance or rebalance impact If I have same consumer group name form different service and different topics

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

For each service we have one specific Kafka topic.
Each service has their Kafka topic and consumer groups for that topic.

- Service1 -> Topic1 -> ConsumerGroup
- Service2 -> Topic2 -> ConsumerGroup
- Service3 -> Topic3 -> ConsumerGroup

Here each Service are consumer of different topics but their consumer group name is same.

If we add another service in the same group, does it affects the other 3 services as they also share the same ConsumerGroup name although they are bind to separate topics? Or if a new consumer gets added to Service3 , Kafka need to rebalance the consumers for the topic partitions? Does it impacts other topics as they are sharing consumer group name?

I think consumer group is tied to the topic, even if other topic consumer has same consumer group name it should not impact.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a new consumer into a group of the same name, it will rebalance, and temporarily stop all other consumers in that group, yes.

Ideally, each service would have its own consumer group if it consumes its own unique topic(s). This way, service restarts would not affect the others.

Comment: Would not consumer group name tied with topic. If consumers being added to a consumer group of one topic. Does it impacts consumer group of another topic with same consumer group name?

Comment: The full group should rebalance

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple consumers subscribed to multiple topics, having same consumer group. But it is recommended to club all the consumer instances of same application subscribed per topic into individual consumer group name, that's how KAFKA achieves **publish->subscribe** implementation pattern with respect to the traditional messaging queues such as TIBCO EMS or IBM Message Broker, because in the KAFKA we only have a single destination or storage called **Topic**, instead of **Queue** or **Topic** as in the traditional system.

This is also to achieve KAFKA native features such as LB (Load Balancing), FT (Fault-Tolerance) and a better membership management per consumer group i.e. per consumer application.

Again, it works, only re-balancing will be an issue for the production like codes.

FYI, Just tested this behaviour in my local, and noted it always re-balances, when a consumer instance (out of 2) getting stopped/started manually.

I am having the following stack.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.5</version>
</parent>


   <confluent.version>5.2.2</confluent.version>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Why does your maven depend on the full Kafka broker, and not `kafka-clients`?